# Troubleshooting Smart Light (Wiz) Problems

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I purchased around a dozen A19 Wiz brand smart lights a few months ago for use in a few ceiling fixtures. Now, the lights have started to fail in rapid succession, across three different fixtures on different circuits. So many have failed (about 10 now), that I'm concerned I have some electrical problem causing them to short out. The manifestation of the failure is that they start to strobe on and off at irregular intervals instead of holding a constant color. Not only the original lights have failed, but at least one of the replacement lights Wiz sent, with a slightly different product number.

I have tested the voltage on switches for two of the fixtures, as well as a socket for a bulb, and the voltage seems to be as expected - 121.7 volts.

But given the large number of failures, what are some other issues I might have that could be causing these failures (beyond the bulbs just being crap)? And how could I test for these other issues?

Thanks for your suggestions!

--- EDIT ---

For reference, here are pictures on two of the fixtures with malfunctioning bulbs. (Some of the bulbs currently installed are still functional in the picture.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the lamps in a hot location? Are the fixtures controlled by a dimmer? Are there voltage spikes (check by putting a lamp on a circuit with surge suppressors, see if it survives)?

Comment: Looking at the Wiz site, I am a bit skeptical about the overall quality for a bunch of reasons, among them no reference to UL or ETL certification. Aside from that, I am really skeptical of the need to put individual light bulbs on a WiFi network, but maybe I'm just old-fashioned.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

The bulbs themselves do have a UL symbol on them. Of course, you are right that smart bulbs are not strictly speaking a necessity of life, but I think they are fun! They can also be useful when you want to dim a light before bedtime. Anyway, if I've got an electrical problem, I do want to try to figure out what it might be.

Comment: Good to hear it has a UL listing. That's no guarantee, but it gives a good indication of safe *design*, which is important. Complexity breeds problems. If all you want is remote dimming - i.e., don't need the colors, etc. - then rather than embed a complex WiFi interface in the base of every bulb (multiplying the number of failure points, putting the WiFi interface in a hot zone, etc.) instead get a smart switch with WiFi that (a) is able to control several bubs at once, (b) is not subject to the heat generated by a light bulb. An LED is several times as efficient as incandescent but still

Comment: produces a lot of heat. Some larger LED fixtures even have fans.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have added some pictures of the fixtures. The room temperature is probably around 69 degrees. The fixtures are not on dimmer switches - just standard switches. One of the fixtures is enclosed, but it only contains a single bulb in each enclosure. The other fixture does not fully enclose the bulbs.